# Ribbon for a web page

Tags: jquery, plugin, gui

is there any other web Ribbon like the one in Sharepoint or this one http://jqueryribbon.codeplex.com/?

Comment: What do you plan on using this for?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-ribbon/) for a ribbon widget that's had some modification in the last few months.